# disk partition centos

Tags: centos, partition, centos6

I am setting up server for hosting two WordPress which has size of around 70GB. I have already installed CentOS as OS and I would like to partition the Disk. Is there any tool which can help me or can someone guide me though the process as I am not expert is SSH commands.

Here are some output that might help.

**OS:** CentOS release 6.3

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/xvdb: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b91e0

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/xvda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e542c

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/xvda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_flourish-lv_root: 16.7 GB, 16718495744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2032 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_flourish-lv_swap: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

**df**

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_flourish-lv_root
                      16070076    758184  14495560   5% /
tmpfs                   958500         0    958500   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1              495844     31926    438318   7% /boot
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_flourish-lv_root
                       16G  741M   14G   5% /
tmpfs                 937M     0  937M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            485M   32M  429M   7% /boot
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with the command-line (Which I VERY MUCH recommend), use the CentOS LVM GUI tool: `system-config-lvm`

This can be installed from the command line with: `yum install system-config-lvm`

Comment: Hi Adrin,

There is a 200GB Partition which is unmounted and unformatted which I would like to use for /home and /backups. IS there any way to add 100GB to /home and leave rest for /backup?

When I ls I get following output.

bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

Comment: Yes, those are folders that are part of your root partition. That's where those new filesystems would get mounted. If you're not aware of how partition table editors work, you're probably on the wrong site and should perhaps ask your questions on SuperUser. There's a certain minimum degree of professional familiarity that we require here.